Filament AdminPanelProvider can't pass Auth()->id()
I'm currently working on a project in FilamnentPHP v3 and Laravel 11 and I am trying to figure out how to pass the current user_id as a parameter in my AdminPanelProvider to a function in the same class.
My AdminPanelProvider class
class AdminPanelProvider extends PanelProvider
{
    public function panel(Panel $panel): Panel
    {
  return $panel
       ->default()
       ->id('admin')
       ->path('admin')
       ->login()
       ->brandName(fn() => auth()->user()->name ?? 'Reporting System') // auth here in brandName is working fine
       ->brandLogo(asset('logo.png'))
       ->brandLogoHeight('4rem')
       ->colors([
                'primary' => Color::Red,
       ])
      ->sidebarCollapsibleOnDesktop()
      ->navigationItems(self::NavigationReportList(fn()=>auth()->user()->id)) // here is my problem

              // rest of  Panel function code

              .....
    }

public static function NavigationReportList($userId)
    {
   dd($userId,Auth()->id(),fn()=>Auth()->id()); // can't get auth id with the three options

[The dd data that i get when trying to get the closure auth id attached below]

  $reports = Report::whereHas('users', function ($query) {
                $query->where('users.id', auth()->id());
            })
                ->select('id')
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->limit(4)
                ->pluck('id')
                ->toArray();


            // rest of my code
             
            .....

    }

So all i want to is to get the auth id inside the static function NavigationReportList
any help will be appreciated
picture of dd of auth id https://i.sstatic.net/7A8JyxCe.jpg

Try using
->navigationItems(self::NavigationReportList(auth()->user()->id))
You must pass the id as a parameter. When you use fn() => auth()->id(), a function is passed as a parameter, not the id. In brandName, it works because it is a filament function, and filament can handle closures.
